encrypt from java and decrypt from python | AES GCM ncryption
I wanted to encrypt a string from Java and decrypt that encrypted value in Python. using AEC GCM algorytham. below is my java code
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AESEncryptionUtil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String encString = "Hello, World!";
        String secKey = "hellow world";
        String encrypted = encrypt(encString, secKey);
        System.out.println("Encrypted (Java): " + encrypted);
        String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, secKey);
        System.out.println("Decrypted (Java): " + decrypted);
    }

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AESEncryption.class);
    private static final String ENCRYPT_ALGO = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
    private static final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128;
    private static final int IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12;
    private static final int SALT_LENGTH_BYTE = 16;
    private static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public static String encrypt(String pText, String secKey) {
        try {
            if (pText == null || pText.equals("null")) {
                return null;
            }
            byte[] salt = getRandomNonce(SALT_LENGTH_BYTE);
            byte[] iv = getRandomNonce(IV_LENGTH_BYTE);
            byte[] keyBytes = secKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(pText.getBytes());
            byte[] cipherTextWithIvSalt =
                    ByteBuffer.allocate(iv.length + salt.length + cipherText.length)
                            .put(iv)
                            .put(salt)
                            .put(cipherText)
                            .array();
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherTextWithIvSalt);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while encrypting:", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String cText, String secKey) {
        try {
            if (cText == null || cText.equals("null")) {
                return null;
            }
            byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cText.getBytes(UTF_8));
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(decode);
            byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH_BYTE];
            bb.get(iv);
            byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH_BYTE];
            bb.get(salt);
            byte[] cipherText = new byte[bb.remaining()];
            bb.get(cipherText);
            byte[] keyBytes = secKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ENCRYPT_ALGO);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
            return new String(plainText, UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error while decrypting:", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] getRandomNonce(int numBytes) {
        byte[] nonce = new byte[numBytes];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonce);
        return nonce;
    }
}

i cannot change my Java code; I tried many ways in Python but was not able to achieve.
most of the time i am getting secretKey decoding error
and cryptography.exceptions.InvalidTag from the Python side.
your suggestions are appreciated.
Python code:
import base64
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

def decrypt(cipher_text_base64, secret_key):
    cipher_text_with_iv_salt = base64.b64decode(cipher_text_base64)
    iv = cipher_text_with_iv_salt[:12]
    salt = cipher_text_with_iv_salt[12:28]
    tag = cipher_text_with_iv_salt[-16:]  # The last 16 bytes are the tag
    ciphertext = cipher_text_with_iv_salt[28:-16]  # Ciphertext excluding tag
    key = secret_key.encode('utf-16')
    key = key[:16].ljust(16, b'\0')
    decryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.GCM(iv, tag), backend=default_backend()).decryptor()
    plaintext = decryptor.update(ciphertext) + decryptor.finalize()
    return plaintext.decode('utf-8')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_to_encrypt = "Hello, World!"
    secret_key = "hellow world"

    # Decrypt in Python
    decrypted_text = decrypt("encrypted_text", secret_key)
    print(f"Decrypted (Python): {decrypted_text}")


Please, post [mre] of your python code, as well sample input, expected output and [full] error.

The Java code includes unknown methods such as CryptoUtils.getRandomNonce(). Please revise the Java code so that it is executable or at least post test data (plaintext, ciphertext).

updated question with updated runnable code

The problem is caused by different encodings of the key.
secret_key.encode('utf-16') in the Java code means by definition big endian with BOM (byte order mark), see Charset, sec. Standard charsets:

When decoding, the UTF-16 and UTF-32 charsets...; when encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark.

In contrast, encode('utf-16') in the Python code is little endian with BOM (at least on my machine; this may depend on the platform’s native byte order).
In the Python code, big endian with BOM can be reliably achieved, e.g. with:
import codecs
...
key = codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE + secret_key.encode('utf-16be')
key = key[:16].ljust(16, b'\0')
...

With this fix decryption works with the Python code.

Although the Java code cannot be changed, future readers should be aware of a vulnerability, namely the derivation of the key from a string with a charset encoding.
Instead, a key derivation function such as Argon2 or at least PBKDF2 should be used in conjunction with a random salt.
Interestingly, a random salt is generated (and later concatenated) in the Java code, but it is not applied   anywhere. It is possible that the use of a dedicated key derivation function was considered, but was not implemented later for some reason.
In addition, for text encodings (such as pText.getBytes()) a specific encoding should always be explicitly specified as otherwise the platform-specific default encoding is used (at least for older Java versions).

Thanks for the solution. much appreciated.
